# How to get rid of yellow box decoration?

Tags: html, css

On many of my input boxes I have a yellow outline that pops up when I select the box. How do I get rid of this?

[image]

Css lint are informing me that:

```
*:focus {
outline: none;
}
```

Should not be used and I quote. `outlines should not be hidden unless other visual changes are made`

When I try:

```
input:focus,
select:focus,
textarea:focus,
button:focus {
outline: none;
}
```

I also get a lint error message but appears to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Override CSS default outline property.

```
input {
   outline: none;
}
```